# php parsing certain values within long text?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I have an array of values, I was wondering how I can parse certain words if the words in my array has the value i'm looking for plus more text?

example:

I'm looking for `rest`

Array values has

```
restful
myrestless
rests
resting
```

What php function, if any, can I use where it will show that there are 4 items that has the word rest?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array('restful', 'myrestless', 'rests', 'resting');

$needle = 'rest';
$rest_array = array_filter( $array, 
    function( $el) use( $needle) { 
        return !(strpos( $el, $needle) === false); 
    }
);
var_dump( $rest_array);
```

Note that this requires PHP >= 5.3 (maybe 5.4?). Otherwise you will have to rewrite it to not use anonymous functions and closures.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OWC7mS)